# Add a border between groups in a definition list when dt and dd are floating?

Tags: html, css

How would you add a line separating definition groups in a definition list, with floating dt and dd elements, without splitting each group into its own list?

I would like this ...

```
<style>
  dl { overflow: auto; }
  dt { float: left; clear: left; }
  dd { float: left; }
</style>

<dl>
  <dt>Term #1</dt>
  <dd>Def #1</dd>
  <dd>Def #2</dd>
  <dd>Def #3</dd>
  <dt>Term #2</dt>
  <dd>Def #1</dd>
  <dd>Def #2</dd>
  <dd>Def #3</dd>
  <dt>Term #3</dt>
  <dd>Def #1</dd>
  <dd>Def #2</dd>
  <dd>Def #3</dd>
</dl>
```

... to display like this ...

```
<style>
  li { border-bottom:1px dashed #000; list-style: none; }
</style>

<ul>
  <li>Term #1 Def #1 Def #2 Def #3</li>
  <li>Term #2 Def #1 Def #2 Def #3</li>
  <li>Term #3 Def #1 Def #2 Def #3</li>
</ul>
```

Note that the continuous border on the li elements doesn't break the dash pattern. If I add a border to each dt and dd element, it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this style

```
<style>
  dt {float:left;clear:left; width:80px; border-bottom:solid 1px #000;}
  dd {float:left; width:50px; border-bottom:solid 1px #000; margin:0;}
</style>
```

Comment: With a dashed border, this breaks the dash pattern and looks a little messy. Maybe there's a way to make the dt border extend over the dd elements?

Answer (score 2):

Is this enough ?

```
dl{border-bottom:1px solid #000;}
dt{border-top:1px solid #000;}
dt:first-child{border-top:0}
```

**demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/nv7fW/1/

Comment: Should tack on an inline display to the dd, and a border to the list.

dd{ display:inline }

http://jsfiddle.net/NWHdn/1/

Comment: Apologies. I've added the the problem by floating the dt and dd elements. Without the block display dt, I lose the ease of just adding a border style to span the full width.